# I'm trying to automate drag and drop a draggable element in dart for flutter_integration testing

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, draggable, flutter-integration-test, dart-test

Trying to automate Drag and drop for testing.
Element is of type Draggable<Student>.

Tried drag() with longPress(). Tried drag with Offset and also tried moveTo() from TestGesture. But still unable to drag the element to the box.

```
//await _tester.longPress(_finder);
//await _tester.drag(_finder, offset);

final Offset firstLocation = _tester.getCenter(_finder);
await _tester.longPress(_finder);
final TestGesture gesture =
    await _tester.startGesture(firstLocation, pointer: 5);
await _tester.pump();
final Offset secondLocation = _tester.getCenter(dropLocation);
await gesture.moveTo(secondLocation);
```

[Widget locator of type Draggable<Student>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaynE.png)
[This is the functionality UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3xeo.png)

Snippet for above function call[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpAhV.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are potentially wrong with this code, but it's difficult to determine without more context.

**Here, a possible solution for your use-case:**

```dart
// Define the target widget to be long-pressed and dragged
final Finder targetFinder = find.byKey(Key('targetWidgetKey'));

// Get the center of the target widget
final Offset firstLocation = _tester.getCenter(targetFinder);

// Long press the target widget
await _tester.longPress(targetFinder);

// Start a gesture at the center of the target widget
final TestGesture gesture = await _tester.startGesture(firstLocation);

// Wait for any animations or other async operations to complete
await _tester.pump();

// Define the location to which the widget will be dragged
final Finder dropFinder = find.byKey(Key('dropWidgetKey'));
final Offset secondLocation = _tester.getCenter(dropFinder);

// Move the gesture to the second location (i.e., drag the widget)
await gesture.moveTo(secondLocation);

// Release the gesture
await gesture.up();

// Wait for any animations or other async operations to complete
await _tester.pump();
```

1. Defined the `targetFinder` and `dropFinder` variables to represent the
   widgets being interacted with. These could be defined using a
   variety of methods, depending on the specific widget hierarchy and
   how the widgets are being tested.
2. Removed the commented-out code and the `offset` variable, since they
   weren't being used in this snippet.
3. Changed the `pointer` argument in `startGesture` to use the default
   value of `null`, since there was no particular reason to specify a
   pointer ID.
4. Added error handling to the code (not shown in this snippet), such
   as checking that the `targetFinder` and `dropFinder` variables are not
   null before using them. This could help prevent crashes and other
   unexpected behaviour.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Not working yet Khader.